# check if child node is of type and access it with xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I made query and stored the result in an $id variable like this:

```
$id = $exampleXPath->query("//li[@class='firstquery']");
```

than I extract data from element of class thirdQuery only if this element is a child element of $id. There is many thirdQuery classes so it needs to be linked to the $id specified by the $counter. Something like this:

```
<class="fisrtQuery">
- <class="childClass">
-> <class="childClass2">

-- <class="grandsonClass">
-- <class="grandsonClass">
--> <class="secondQuery">
--- <class="sfd">
--- <class="sfd">
--- <class="thirdQuery">


for ($counter=0 ; $counter<60 ; $counter++){
if($id->item($counter)->hasChildNodeOfClassThirdQuery){
    echo nodeOfClassThirdQuery->item(0)->nodeValue;
     }
}
```

Does php comes with the power of traversing child nodes  easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your hypothetical codes correctly, it can be translated roughly into something like this :

```
$id = $exampleXPath->query("//li[@class='firstquery']");

$xpath = "./*[position() < 61]/*[@class='thirdQuery']";
$result = $exampleXPath->query($xpath, $id);
```

Explanation of the XPath :

- **`./*[position() < 61]`** : Get child elements of current context element `$id`, at index less than `61`. XPath index starts from `1`, so this is about equal to *'looping through child elements at index `0` to `59`'* in PHP.
- **`/*[@class='thirdQuery']`** : Get child elements of current context element, where `class` attribute value equals `"thirdQuery"`. Here context element is child of `$id` as returned by XPath bit in the previous point above